# How to retrieve a collection of values from a HashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I'm writing a function to test if a HashMap has null values. The method .values() SHOULD return a collection of just the values, but instead I receive a map with both the keys and values stored inside. This is no good as the purpose of my function is to check if the values are null, but if I return a map with keys AND values then .values().isEmpty() returns false if I have a key stored with no value.

```
  public Map<KEY, List<VALUES>> methodName() {
    if (MAPNAME.values().isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomErrorException(ExceptionHandler.getErrorWithDescription(ErrorConstants.ERROR_MSG_01));
        } else {
            return MAPNAME;
        }
    }
```

In the above example, .values() always returns a map containing all the keys and values. My method never throws a CustomErrorException if the HashMap has a key, which is bad since it's supposed to detect if there are no values. Help!

Comment: @jahroy Map<KEY, List<VALUES>> MAPNAME = new HashMap<KEY, List<VALUES>>();

Comment: HashMaps allow null values and a single null key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as a Map implementation that has a key stored without a value. All Map implementations either:

- throw an exception in `put` when the value is null
- Add an entry with a key and a value of null

A key that maps to null is very different than a key without a value. The key has a value, and that value is null (and that means that the values collection won't be empty, unless the map is empty). A key without a value is a key that's not contained in the map.

Long story short, you probably want to use `MAPNAME.values().contains(null)` or even just `MAPNAME.containsValue(null)` to do what you want. Alternatively, if you're checking that *every* key maps to null, check that by iterating over the .values() collection.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the concept of Maps for me. Using MAPNAME.values().contains(null) works well for my purpose. One last thing - what exactly is .values() supposed to do? In my case, it returned the entire hash map, keys AND values. I just wanted an array of values to perform logic on.

Comment: Sorry, but you're mistaken on that front. HashMap.values() definitely does not return a HashMap. As HashMap and Map don't implement Collection, HashMap wouldn't even compile if it returned itself from values(). The values() method returns a Collection containing every value referred to by a key. There can be duplicates (it's not a set), so if 3 keys map to `null`, then `null` will be in the Collection 3 times. Also, removing a value from the values Collection will update the map as well.

Comment: In eclipse, if I walked through my code in the debugger and I examine what 'values' contains in my HashMap, it says 'this'. If I expand 'this', it contains the entire HashMap, including keys and values (values leads to another 'this', leading to a series of infinite HashMaps contained within one another). Just sayin'

Comment: That's different. That means that the class returned by values() contains a reference to the original HashMap, not that it *is* the original HashMap. The likely reason for this is that the values() Collection returned by HashMap is an inner class of HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the map -- MAPNAME, not the values:

```
return MAPNAME.values();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - I am returning the HashMap. My problem is that my if statement will NEVER throw an error exception if there is a key in the HashMap, which is no go as there are theoretical scenarios where the HashMap will store keys but no values. 

It is not the goal of this method to simply return the values of the HashMap, but to return the entire HashMap if the values are not empty/null.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to determine if the map contains any null values, you should iterate over the collection of values and check each one to see if its null.

A map that contains an entry with a null value is not empty.

Comment: The problem is MAPNAME.values() is returning a hash map, even though the documentation and several examples state it should return a collection. Actually, it says the value of 'values' is 'this', aka the  hash map 'values' is stored in.

Comment: Then more specifically, what I need is for MAPNAME.values() to return a collection of ONLY the values with NO keys stored inside. This is not currently the case, because MAPNAME.values() returns a map containing all keys and all values. Isn't this the way that .values() is supposed to work?

Comment: How could there possibly be a key with no value? What do you mean by "ONLY the values with NO keys stored inside"?  Each element of a Map involves a key that is mapped to a value.  Every key must have a value and every value must have an associated key. Some Maps can contain null keys and null values.  Others can not.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being very clear about what you want -- your map values are lists -- considering that, there are three ways to have a key map to "no values":

- A key mapped to `null` (then the test is `map.values().contains(null)` )
- A key mapped to an empty list (then the test is `map.values().contains(Collections.emptyList())` )
- A key mapped to a list full of `null`s.

What your method above is doing right now is throwing an exception if the map is truly empty (no keys), and returning the map otherwise.

It is not clear what you want. If you want the method to throw an exception only if the map has no meaningful values (all keys map either to null or to empty lists) then something like this is what you need:

```
public Map<KEY, List<VALUES>> methodName() {
    for( List<VALUES> values : MAPNAME.values() ) // 1
        if( null != values ) // 2
            for( VALUES value : values ) // 3
                if( null != value ) // 4
                    return MAPNAME;

    throw new CustomErrorException(ExceptionHandler.getErrorWithDescription(ErrorConstants.ERROR_MSG_01));
}
```

This throws an exception in the all reasonably conceivable "empty map" scenarios -- if (1) the map is truly empty, or (2) it contains only `null` keys, or (3) it only contains only `null` values or empty lists, or (4) it contains only `null` values or empty lists or lists of `null`s.

(Levels of "emptiness" tests in the text above correspond to the comment labels in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Use the values() method in this way:-
Collection set=MAPNAME.values();

And then use a foreach loop to check if every value is null or not.

Comment: *Collection<type> set=MAPNAME.values();

Comment: Oh yes! Totally forgot about it. Thank you!